# What is /run/mount/utab?

Tags: linux

In exploring a hung `umount`, I bumped into `/run/mount/utab` in some `strace` output.

What is the purpose of `/run/mount/utab`?

Where can I read more about `/run/mount/utab`:

- purpose
- format
- what interacts with it (and how)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the purpose of `/run/mount/utab`?

The file is used by `mount` to store the user who mounted a filesystem. From `man mount`, under `FILESYSTEM-INDEPENDENT MOUNT OPTIONS` (and some quick tests)

```
user   Allow  an ordinary user to mount the filesystem.  The name of the mounting user
       is written to the mtab file (or to the private libmount file in  /run/mount  on
       systems without a regular mtab) so that this same user can unmount the filesys‐
       tem again.
```

In other words, if you have a drive you want to mount as ordinary user, you probably use an entry in `/etc/fstab`, containing the UUID of the device (or other identifier) and the option `user`, for example

```
UUID=<UUID> <target> ... user ...
```

When you `$ mount -U <UUID>` as user `user1`, `mount` will write something like the following to `/run/mount/utab`

```
SRC=/dev/sdb1 TARGET=<target> ROOT=/ OPTS=user=user1
```

which allows you to unmount the device.

> Where can I read more about `/run/mount/utab`

The format is straight forward, provided you see the same as I see on my system, and apart from what written above, that's pretty much all I could find, try to check the links from the [other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/406261/226824).

Answer (score 2):

After a quick read of [libmount-tables-update](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.23/libmount-docs/libmount-Tables-update.html) I believe the file is used to store userspace mount options. I'd have a look around [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.23/libmount-docs/) for information around the API's and how to interact with it. The source code for util-linux which contains [libmount](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/) might also be another place to look.